# How Reduce function really work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, maxlength

I'm trying to use reduce function in order to find the max length array in **arrays**
so I tried this approach at first but it didn't work

```
const arrays = [[1],[3,3,4],[3,4],[4,5],[6]]
let maxLength = arrays.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
    return acc.length > cur.length ? acc.length : cur.length
})

console.log(maxLength) // output : 1
```

so I tried to get the length in another way and it worked

```
const arrays = [[1],[3,3,4],[3,4],[4,5],[6]]
let maxLength = arrays.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
    return acc.length > cur.length ? acc : cur
}).length

console.log(maxLength) // output : 3
```

Can someone Explain what is the difference between the two approaches ?

Comment: Think about what the **type** of `acc` is. It cannot simultaneously be a `number` and an `Array`. I recommend you repeat your experiment but in the TypeScript Playground to see why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code, the reduce function is returning a number, while in the second, it is returning an array. When you're returning a number, the next time your function is called, it takes the length of a number, not an array. The second code is correct, because you're taking the length of an array every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the length of the longest array, store the length in the accumulator (as in the first example); if you're interested in the array with the longest length, store the array in the accumulator (as in the second example). What you can't do is mix and match.

### Get the length of the longest array

In this case, you need to provide an initial value (e.g. `0`) to [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const arrays = [[1],[3,3,4],[3,4],[4,5],[6]];

const max = arrays.reduce((a, {length}) => Math.max(a, length), 0);

console.log(max);
```

### Get array with the longest length

In this case, you don't need to provide an initial value as it defaults to the first element of the array.

```js
const arrays = [[1],[3,3,4],[3,4],[4,5],[6]];

const max = arrays.reduce((a, v) => v.length > a.length ? v : a);

console.log(max);
```

Comment: I'll admit that's a pretty neat-trick by extracting `Array.prototype.length` in a destructed parameter there: `(a, {length}) =>`.

Comment: @Dai `length` is *not* a property on the prototype, it's an array's own property. `[].hasOwnProperty("length")`